# Introduction to Groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

So, I know that the operation "multiplication" in a group is not familiar old multiplication with real numbers.  So, exponents in groups is not the same as exponents when dealing with real numbers.

I cannot assume $a^ma^n$=$a^{m+n}$, nor $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$.

How do I go about setting up the proof for 
If a ∈ G and n ∈ N then both $(a^n)^{-1}$ and $(a^{-1})^n$ have unambiguous interpretations in terms of the definitions already given. Prove that these two are in fact equal.

Proof: (by Mathematical Induction)
[The Basis Step]
Let n = 1.  Then, for n = 1, $(a^n)^{-1}$=$(a^1)^{-1}$=$a^{-1}$=$(a^{-1})^1$=$(a^{-1})^n$.
So, for n=1, $(a^n)^{-1}$=$(a^{-1})^n$.
[End of Basis Step]
[Inductive Step]
Let k ∈ N.
Suppose that $(a^k)^{-1}$=$(a^{-1})^k$.
Since $(a^k)^{-1}$=$(a^{-1})^k$,
then $(a^{(k+1)})^{-1}$

Comment: you "cannot assume $a^ma^n$=$a^{m+n}$, nor $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$" but they are true and easy to prove.

Comment: You can assume the exponent laws. You can prove them by using the the fact that the multiplication operation is associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for $n=1$, $(a^{-1})^1 = a^{-1}$ and $(a^1)^{-1}= a^{-1}$. So both sides are equal.

If $(a^{-1})^k= (a^k)^{-1}$ by induction hypothesis, then $(a^{k+1})^{-1} = (a^k a)^{-1} = a^{-1} (a^k)^{-1}$

where I have used that $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$, and then

$a^{-1} (a^k)^{-1} = a^{-1} (a^{-1})^k$

by induction and then

$a^{-1} (a^{-1})^k = (a^{-1})^{k+1}.$

Moreover, I have used the definition of taking powers: $a^1=a$, $a^{k+1}=a^ka$ for $k\geq 1$.

Comment: I understand everything you did up to the last part on the right hand side of the induction step.  How did you get from $a^{−1}(a^{−1})^k$  to   $(a^{−1})^{k+1}$.?

Comment: This is explained in the last sentence - taking powers.

Comment: No, $g g^k = g^{k+1}$. Use $g=a^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah. I see, nevermind.  I'm overthinking it.

Comment: Thank you very much.